# I'm trying to see the revenue on the past three month (curent date April 15th, 2022)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following codes, but it is not producing the expected outcome.

```
with revenue1 as


( select
format_date('%y,%m', (b.created_at)) as dates,

a.category as category,

a.name as product_name,

b.product_id as product_id,

cast(sum(b.sale_price)*count(b.order_id) as int64) as sales

from 'bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products' a

Join 'bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items' b

on b.product_id=a.id

where lower(b.status) =complete

group by 1,4,3,2)

,revenue2 as

( select *,

round(sum(sales)over(partition by category order by dates),2) as 
total_revenue

from revenue1

where revenue1.dates between 2022-02-01 and 2022-02-15)
```

I'm expecting the output :
Date (in date format)
Product Categories
Revenue

But it's not working, stated : `Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got end of script at [18:6]`

Comment: Quick observation - If this is the exact query you are trying to execute, enclose dates with single quotes.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would go along way to helping others answer your question. A https://dbfiddle.uk would be even better

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not reading carefully, but I see two CTEs but no SELECT after they're defined. You need a SELECT to get the data you need out of the CTEs you created.

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT... FROM ...)
, table2 AS (SELECT... FROM ...)
/* etc */

SELECT table1.SomeValue1...., tabel2.SomeValue2
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ....
```

Is there more to your original question?